# EventBridge Enrichment change value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I have a lambda working as a bridge between my SQS and a Step function.

An S3 createObject sends a message to my queue that triggers this lambda.

My lambda only transforms the key object and invokes my SF as follows :

```
const body = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);
const key = decodeURIComponent(body.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
const Bucket = body.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
const fileName = key.split(".")[0];

const jsonInput = {
    Bucket,
    Key: `${fileName}.json`
}

return await invokeStepFunction(jsonInput, `exec-${new Date().toISOString()}-${fileName}`);
```

I want to know if it's possible to do the same, get the key name and change the extension, using only an EventBridge and transform the data on the Enrichment step.

sample:

```
{
  "body": {
    "Records": [{
      "s3": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": "test-1"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test.mp4"
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

transformer:

```
{
    "Bucket": <$.body.Records[0].s3.bucket.name>
    "Key": <$.body.Records[0].s3.object.key>
}
```

desired output:

```
{
  "Bucket": "test-1",
  "Key": "test.json"
}
```

Is it possible to use any String function, such as, replace or substring at the "Transformer" step on EventBridge?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible using just EventBridge transformer. How you are using the Lambda function is the way I would recommend to get the output you want.